# Run Jenkins Pipeline Tests Inside Docker Container

Tags: dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to run my pipeline tests inside (or against) a docker container that I have. I originally used a Dockerfile to create the container, but the tests would always run against the jenkins node executing the job. I modified my jenkinsfile to use something standard, but still don't get what I expect.

What I'm ultimately trying to accomplish is:

1. Throw up a docker container
2. Copy my source code to the container
3. Run my python script on the container

I've got 1 & 2 working, but not 3. For now I'd be happy if I could just run tests against a container, which is why I modified the Jenkinsfile to be simpler.

My Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { image 'node:7-alpine' }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'pwd'
                sh 'ls -al'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run `docker run node:7-alpine pwd`, `docker run node:7-alpine ls -al` locally, I get the following:

```
/
```

and

```
bin
dev
etc
home
lib
linuxrc
media
mnt
opt
proc
root
run
sbin
srv
sys
tmp
usr
var
```

But on Jenkins I get:

```
[test_job] Running shell script
+ pwd
/srv/jenkins/workspace/test_job
```

and

```
[test_job] Running shell script
+ ls -al
total 36
drwxr-x---    4 5003     5003          4096 Aug 29 20:44 .
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root          4096 Aug 29 20:44 ..
drwxr-x---    8 5003     5003          4096 Aug 29 20:44 .git
-rw-r-----    1 5003     5003          1184 Aug 29 19:24 .gitignore
-rw-r-----    1 5003     5003           802 Aug 29 19:47 Dockerfile
-rw-r-----    1 5003     5003           247 Aug 29 20:44 Jenkinsfile
-rw-r-----    1 5003     5003           417 Aug 29 20:24 OriginalJenkinsfile
-rw-r-----    1 5003     5003          2534 Aug 29 19:24 README.md
drwxr-x---    5 5003     5003          4096 Aug 29 19:24 framework
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know these commands mount the current directory from jenkins into the container and sets it as workdir. Also there is a bug and you can not switch directory inside the container.

Try ls / which should list whatever is in the root directory of that container

Comment: I'm using the docker pipeline plugin, my code is actually the first example mentioned here: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/ - but the test steps aren't working as described.

Comment: Have a look at my edited answer. You expect to ls the root directory of the docker container. But you actually list the contents of a mounted directory. Try 'ls /'